# Which is the secured way of scripting registration form?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In many sites, I have seen after clicking on "Sign Up" or "Register" button we are either re-directed to other page where the insertion of our data in database takes place. Like in Facebook, when you click "Sign Up" it goes to the `facebook.com/r.php` page. I want to create a registration form which when submitted, will be not re-directed but will validate and insert data in database in the same page.

For example, Facebook uses a form such as:

```
<form id="xyZ" name="abc" method="post" action="r.php">
```

It redirects us from `index.php` to `r.php`.

But I want to use:

```
<form id="xyZ" name="abc" method="post" action="index.php">
```

i.e Without redirecting.

Which one is safe?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting does not effect the security of the website at all in the slightest. I recommend taking a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045702/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-php-login-page) about possible authentication solutions you can use for your site.

Whether you authenticate and log them in/register them using `index.php` or `r.php`, it doesn't matter in the slightest. Forum systems such as `phpbb` used to at one time to everything in the `index.php` file, and depending on the `?page` `$_GET` variable, it would display different things (Like a login form, or a registration form). How you handle it, is entirely up to you, but neither method is more insecure than the others.

Answer (score 0):

Both are safe!

1. Redirect method, kind of link using which user redirects to another page where they can register
2. Ajax Method, here you can make calls using Javascript / jQuery which returns you html source, which you can just plug in appropriate place.

Your Page where you need your registration form to be displayed, when user click on `sign up` link

```
<div id="ajax-response"></div>
<a id="signup" href="signup.php">SignUp</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#signup").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _context = this;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: jQuery(_context).attr('href'),
        success: function(response){
            jQuery("#ajax-response").html(response);
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

and signup.php, will contain the registration form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```